# R shiny Bug: Problem of plot when we change data sets. It shows " undefined columns selected"

Tags: r, shiny

I want to run the following code for a R shiny app. I have four different data sets, some of the datasets has 160 columns and some has 50 columns. They don't have all the same name except the columns "Groups", "Mouse.ID","Cohort" and "Color". In the columns group they don't have the same name of the groups.
The problem is that it takes time to load the plot, and when we change data set we have at the beginning "undefined columns selected" as a warning message. How could I prevent this ?

Thank you so much

```
#Load  data: 
data_073 <- read_csv("Study_ACI073.csv")
data_074 <- read.csv("Study_ACI074.csv")
data_071 <- read.csv("Study_ACI071.csv")
data_077 <- read.csv("Study_ACI077.csv")

# Define all the desired input on the left and the output ( plot and table)
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("R_shiny"),
  
  # Sidebar with conditional Panel depending if we want a correlation or a data plot. First we choose the type of plot.
  # Depending on the choice, several options are available: for data plot, we have : type of transformations, choices for the variable,plot by cohort ans which groups of treatment. 
  
  # For correlation plot, we need to choose the X-axis variable, the Y-axis variable, the number of groups and the name of the labels for the axes.
  sidebarPanel(
    
    selectInput("data_set", label = "Select the data set", choices = c("Study ACI071", "Study ACI073","Study ACI074", "Study ACI077")),
    
    selectInput("Var1", label="Choose the X-axis", choices = NULL),
    selectInput("Var2", label="Choose the Y-axis", choices = NULL),
    textInput("lab_x","Label for X-axis",value=" "),
    textInput("lab_y","Label for Y-axis",value=" "),
    checkboxGroupInput("Groups","Groups:",NULL),
    radioButtons("transformation", "Transformations:", c("None"="no", "Square root"="sqrt", "Logarithm"="log")),
    checkboxInput("cohort", "Plot by cohort", FALSE),
    checkboxInput("viz", "Reset visualization",FALSE)
    
    
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1",click="plot_click"),
    plotOutput("plot2"),
    tableOutput("info"),
    verbatimTextOutput("selected"),
    br(),
    tableOutput("summary"),
    br(),
    br(),
    downloadLink("downloadPlot1", "Download Correlation Plot"),
    br(),
    downloadLink("downloadPlot2", "Download Data Plot"),
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output,session){
  
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    if(req(input$data_set) == "Study ACI071"){
      a <- data_071
    } else if (req(input$data_set) == "Study ACI073"){
      a <- data_073
    } else if(req(input$data_set) == "Study ACI074"){
      a <- data_074
    } else{
      a <- data_077
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    datasetinput <- datasetInput()
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "Groups", choices = levels(as.factor(datasetinput$Group)), selected = levels(as.factor(datasetinput$Group)))
    updateSelectInput(session, "Var1", choices = names(select_if(datasetinput,is.numeric)),selected = "FrCtx.AT8.Class3.OD")
    updateSelectInput(session, "Var2", choices = names(select_if(datasetinput,is.numeric)), selected = "FrCtx.AT8.Class4.OD")
  })
  
  dataset_plot <- reactive({
    dataset <- datasetInput()
    dat <- dataset[c(input$Var1, input$Var2,"Group","Color","Mouse.ID")]
    colnames(dat) <- c("Var1","Var2","Group","Color","Id")
    dat <- dat[dat$Group %in% input$Groups,]
    dat <- na.omit(dat)
    return(dat)
  })
  
  data_color <- reactive({
    dataset <- datasetInput()
    dat <- dataset[c(input$Var1, input$Var2,"Group","Color","Mouse.ID")]
    colnames(dat) <- c("Var1","Var2","Group","Color","Id")
    order_color <- levels(as.factor(dat$Color))
    names(order_color) <- levels(as.factor(dat$Group))
    dat <- dat[dat$Group %in% input$Groups,]
    dat <- na.omit(dat)
    order_color <- order_color[names(order_color) %in% input$Groups]
    return(order_color)
  })
  
  my_plot1 <- function(){
    order_color <- data_color()
    dat <- dataset_plot()
    if(length(dat$Group) != 0){
      ggplot(dat,aes(y=Var2, x=Var1,color = Group)) + geom_point(size= 3.5) + scale_y_continuous(input$lab_y) + scale_x_continuous(input$lab_x) + theme(axis.title=element_text(size=15))+ 
        theme_bw()+ scale_color_manual(values = order_color, name = "Group", labels = names(order_color)) + 
        theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
        labs(title = paste("Correlation plot of: ",input$lab_y, "on the Y-axis and ", input$lab_x, "on the X-axis"))
    }
  }
  
  my_plot2_no <- function(){
    dat <- dataset_plot()
    order_color <- data_color()
    
    if(input$cohort == FALSE){
      
      p1 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=Group,y=Var1,color=Group)) + geom_sina(size=3.5) + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,fun.args=list(mult=1),geom="errorbar",width=0.3,size=1.2) +
        stat_summary(fun=base::mean,geom="crossbar",width=0.8) + scale_y_continuous(input$lab_x)+ scale_x_discrete(" ",labels = names(order_color)) + 
        theme_bw() + scale_color_manual(values = order_color) +
        theme(legend.position = "none") +
        labs(title = paste("Plot of: ", input$lab_x)) 
      
      p2 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=Group,y=Var2,color=Group)) + geom_sina(size=3.5) + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,fun.args=list(mult=1),geom="errorbar",width=0.3,size=1.2) +
        stat_summary(fun=base::mean,geom="crossbar",width=0.8) + scale_y_continuous(input$lab_y)+ scale_x_discrete("", labels = names(order_color)) + 
        theme_bw() +  scale_color_manual(values = order_color) +
        theme(legend.position = "none") +
        labs(title = paste("Plot of: ", input$lab_y)) 
      
      plot_grid(p1 ,p2 )
    }else{
      
      p1 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=Group,y=Var1,colour= Group)) + geom_sina(size=3.5) + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,fun.args=list(mult=1),geom="errorbar",width=0.3,size=1.2) +
        stat_summary(fun=base::mean,geom="crossbar",width=0.8) + scale_y_continuous(input$lab_x) + scale_x_discrete("") + 
        theme_bw()+ scale_color_manual(values = order_color, labels = names(order_color), name = "Group") +theme(legend.position = "bottom",axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.title=element_text(size=15)) +
        labs(title = paste("Plot of: ", input$lab_x)) + facet_wrap(~Cohort, ncol=3) 
      
      p2 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=Group,y=Var2,colour= Group)) + geom_sina(size=3.5) + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,fun.args=list(mult=1),geom="errorbar",width=0.3,size=1.2) +
        stat_summary(fun=base::mean,geom="crossbar",width=0.8) + scale_y_continuous(input$lab_y) + scale_x_discrete("") + 
        theme_bw()+ scale_color_manual(values = order_color, labels = names(order_color), name = "Group")+ theme(legend.position = "bottom",axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.title=element_text(size=15)) +
        facet_wrap(~Cohort, ncol=3) 
      
      plot_grid(p1,p2)
    }
  }
  
  my_plot2_sqrt <- function(){
    dat <- dataset_plot()
    order_color <- data_color()
    
    if(input$cohort == FALSE){
      
      p1 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=Group,y=sqrt(Var1),color=Group)) + geom_sina(size=3.5) + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,fun.args=list(mult=1),geom="errorbar",width=0.3,size=1.2) +
        stat_summary(fun=base::mean,geom="crossbar",width=0.8) + scale_y_continuous(paste("Square root of",input$lab_x)) + scale_x_discrete(" ",labels = names(order_color)) + 
        theme_bw() + scale_color_manual(values = order_color) +
        theme(legend.position = "none") +
        labs(title = paste("Plot of: ", input$lab_x)) 
      
      p2 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=Group,y=sqrt(Var2),color=Group)) + geom_sina(size=3.5) + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,fun.args=list(mult=1),geom="errorbar",width=0.3,size=1.2) +
        stat_summary(fun=base::mean,geom="crossbar",width=0.8)  + scale_y_continuous(paste("Square root of",input$lab_y)) + scale_x_discrete("", labels = names(order_color)) + 
        theme_bw() +  scale_color_manual(values = order_color) +
        theme(legend.position = "none") +
        labs(title = paste("Plot of: ", input$lab_y)) 
      
      plot_grid(p1 ,p2 )
    }else{
      
      p1 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=Group,y=sqrt(Var1),colour= Group)) + geom_sina(size=3.5) + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,fun.args=list(mult=1),geom="errorbar",width=0.3,size=1.2) +
        stat_summary(fun=base::mean,geom="crossbar",width=0.8) + scale_y_continuous(paste("Square root of",input$lab_x)) + scale_x_discrete("") + 
        theme_bw()+ scale_color_manual(values = order_color, labels = names(order_color), name = "Group") +theme(legend.position = "bottom",axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.title=element_text(size=15)) +
        labs(title = paste("Plot of: ", input$lab_x)) + facet_wrap(~Cohort, ncol=3) 
      
      p2 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=Group,y=sqrt(Var2),colour= Group)) + geom_sina(size=3.5) + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,fun.args=list(mult=1),geom="errorbar",width=0.3,size=1.2) +
        stat_summary(fun=base::mean,geom="crossbar",width=0.8) + scale_y_continuous(paste("Square root of",input$lab_y)) + scale_x_discrete("") + 
        theme_bw()+ scale_color_manual(values = order_color, labels = names(order_color), name = "Group")+ theme(legend.position = "bottom",axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.title=element_text(size=15)) +
        facet_wrap(~Cohort, ncol=3) 
      
      plot_grid(p1,p2)
    }
  }
  
  my_plot2_log <- function(){
    dat1 <- dataset_plot()
    order_color <- data_color()
    
    if(input$cohort == FALSE){
      
      p1 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=Group,y=log(Var1),color=Group)) + geom_sina(size=3.5) + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,fun.args=list(mult=1),geom="errorbar",width=0.3,size=1.2) +
        stat_summary(fun=base::mean,geom="crossbar",width=0.8) + scale_y_continuous(paste("Log of",input$lab_x)) + scale_x_discrete(" ",labels = names(order_color)) + 
        theme_bw() + scale_color_manual(values = order_color) +
        theme(legend.position = "none") +
        labs(title = paste("Plot of: ", input$lab_x)) 
      
      p2 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=Group,y=log(Var2),color=Group)) + geom_sina(size=3.5) + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,fun.args=list(mult=1),geom="errorbar",width=0.3,size=1.2) +
        stat_summary(fun=base::mean,geom="crossbar",width=0.8)  + scale_y_continuous(paste("Log of",input$lab_y)) + scale_x_discrete("", labels = names(order_color)) + 
        theme_bw() +  scale_color_manual(values = order_color) +
        theme(legend.position = "none") +
        labs(title = paste("Plot of: ", input$lab_y)) 
      
      plot_grid(p1 ,p2 )
    }else{
      
      p1 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=Group,y=log(Var1),colour= Group)) + geom_sina(size=3.5) + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,fun.args=list(mult=1),geom="errorbar",width=0.3,size=1.2) +
        stat_summary(fun=base::mean,geom="crossbar",width=0.8) + scale_y_continuous(paste("Log of",input$lab_x)) + scale_x_discrete("") + 
        theme_bw()+ scale_color_manual(values = order_color, labels = names(order_color), name = "Group") +theme(legend.position = "bottom",axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.title=element_text(size=15)) +
        labs(title = paste("Plot of: ", input$lab_x)) + facet_wrap(~Cohort, ncol=3) 
      
      p2 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=Group,y=log(Var2),colour= Group)) + geom_sina(size=3.5) + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,fun.args=list(mult=1),geom="errorbar",width=0.3,size=1.2) +
        stat_summary(fun=base::mean,geom="crossbar",width=0.8) + scale_y_continuous(paste("Log of",input$lab_y)) + scale_x_discrete("") + 
        theme_bw()+ scale_color_manual(values = order_color, labels = names(order_color), name = "Group")+ theme(legend.position = "bottom",axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.title=element_text(size=15)) +
        facet_wrap(~Cohort, ncol=3) 
      
      plot_grid(p1,p2)
    }
  }
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot(my_plot1())
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    if(input$transformation == "no"){
      my_plot2_no()
    } else if(input$transformation == "sqrt"){
      my_plot2_sqrt()
    } else{
      my_plot2_log()
    }
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your code is neither minimal (227 lines) nor reproducible (we don't have access to your csv files).  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide an example that is both. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is bulky and not reproducible, as noted by @Limey, so it's hard to help.

That said, could you try that:

```
  observe({
    datasetinput <- datasetInput()
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "Groups")
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "Groups", choices = levels(as.factor(datasetinput$Group)), selected = levels(as.factor(datasetinput$Group)))
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "Var1")
    updateSelectInput(session, "Var1", choices = names(select_if(datasetinput,is.numeric)),selected = "FrCtx.AT8.Class3.OD")
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "Var2")
    updateSelectInput(session, "Var2", choices = names(select_if(datasetinput,is.numeric)), selected = "FrCtx.AT8.Class4.OD")
  })
```